# Change text color, unbold and size

Tags: excel, vba

I hope everyone is well. I need some help regarding with my macro code. What I want is to have a macro code that will change the font size, color and un-bold on specific sheets from a2-w2 or until the last row that contain data. I'm not sure what needs to be done, I know I can change the range to a2-w350, but what if there is more rows than 350. Is there a way to change it until the last row data?

```
[Sub format()
with worksheet("Temp").Range("A2:w2")
.Font.size = 11
.Font.Color = vbBlack
.Font.Bold = False

end with
end sub]
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code (rather than type it)

Comment: Oh. I didn't know. It's actually my first time, but thank you for the advise. Will do it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **(not tested)**

```
sub format()
with worksheet("Temp")
With .Range("A2:w" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count) 'Fixed

.Font.size = 11
.Font.Color = vbBlack
.Font.Bold = False

End With
end with
end sub
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working. Really appreciate, I'm not really familiar with the last row count. But thank you. Really help.

Comment: Depending on the situation, you can use the above method. Alternatively, you can use `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. This is the same as going to the last cell in column A (A1048576) and pressing `Ctrl`+`Up` and then reading the row number. Here I used column A, you need to select a column of your database that you know will not have blank cells.